# How To Get javascript Array in Code behind

Tags: javascript, arrays, c#-4.0

This is javascript array

```
var data =['athar','naveed','123','abx'];
```

Now I want to access this array in code behind array or list variable. Don't want to use Hidden field.

Comment: The values in the Array will need to be communicated between the layers over HTTP, through a `<form>` field and submission or with an [Ajax request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).

Comment: You can post it via AJAX but these suggestions depends on your design. You need to be more spesific.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use in anyother javascript function,you can simply use data[0] to access first element i.e.,athar.
data.length will give you the count of values present in the array.